# Do javascript after redirect

Tags: javascript

I redirect to a new page with javascript as

```
window.location.href = new_page;
```

When the new page loaded, I want to run some javascript functions.

However, how can I detect when a page loads, it is from my above redirect?

I consider two options: creating a session or passing variables via the URL as

```
window.location.href = new_page+'&redirected=1';
```

Then checking if `redirected` query is set on each page.

***I wonder if there is a simpler or more standard approach to do so?***

Comment: Unless you control that site, then you can't.

Comment: Long answer short, you can’t. Otherwise it’s going to be a huge security issue. Imagine redirecting users to an online bank url and manipulating the page using JS.

Comment: Using session makes sense if this is all on same domain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing parameters throught URL works fine, but it's not a pretty good solution. I suggest you to try [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), with this solution you even could track from and to urls the user has been redirected.